# MySQL access denied?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, environment

Stack: PHP, Laravel. Used Vs-code and tableplus.

My goal was to follow along in the laracast video series to try and learn laravel /php coding.

During the video series, I did create and connect to mySQL database. At some point, not sure what I did, but I cannot connect to the database at all when using terminal or tableplus (which was connected previously).

In the terminal I enter `MySQL -u root` but I am greeted with password (which there isn't one) then I hit enter and an error appears. It was functioning before but I am not sure what I did that now throws this error. As you can see below in the code under DB_Password'' there is nothing assigned.

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

**.env** file below:

````
LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=laravel 
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log CACHE_DRIVER=file QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync SESSION_DRIVER=file SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1 REDIS_PASSWORD=null REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io MAIL_PORT=2525 MAIL_USERNAME=null MAIL_PASSWORD=null MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID= PUSHER_APP_KEY= PUSHER_APP_SECRET= PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}" MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"'''

From my understanding (google) this is a mysql issue and not larvael?!?

I am not really sure what else to do here...

Here is the PostsContoller.php  (incase its needed)

```<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers; use Illuminate\Http\Request; use DB; use App\Post; class PostsController extends Controller { public function show($slug) { $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first(); if (! $post) { abort(404); } return view('post',[ 'post' => $post ]); } ```

**Additional error code in terminal:** 

 ``` catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }```

 Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
      /Users/paolo/Desktop/webapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=laravel", "root", "", [])
      /Users/paolo/Desktop/webapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
````

Comment: If it's saying that there's a password, so it have a password... How did you installed mysql?

Comment: See https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.techrepublic.com/google-amp/article/how-to-set-change-and-recover-a-mysql-root-password/

Comment: Hi @Mohammad see below for the install method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after much back and forth, the issue was I was trying to log into the MYSQL database but using the .env laravel inputs like username: abc and password:123 that I changed and saved in the .env laravel project file.

Instead, I went through terminal and was able to log into MYSQL using u-root. I then proceeded to create a new database that was named the same as in the .env with the above credentials username:abc password:123.

Success, I was finally able to get control of the database again.

I hope that in turn helps anyone who may be experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `sudo` totally the wrong tool. That's like running your browser as root in order to get access to your online banking. No, the server issues an authentication request to a client. That server neither knows nor cares what user you are running as. Note that in order to add to the confusion, the "default" user of MySQL is often named "root", just like the admin user on Unix systems.

Now, concerning your problem, it is simply that there is a password which you may not be aware of. An often-used combination of username and password for MySQL installations is "root" and "root" (obviously extremely unsafe, but just for local use).

If that doesn't work, you will have to use more low-level administration tools, which further depends on your installation. Those will then use OS-level access to the DB, which may need to be done using `sudo`. Can you share some info on how you installed, on what system etc.? If you haven't found a way, that may provide the additional info required to nudge you into the right direction.

Comment: Hi @UIrich the installation setup first went to .env file and next to ```DB_DATABASE=laravel ``` I inputted the database name laravel. I then went to terminal signed via mysql -u root, then create database:laravel; Next, I used typescript named it localhost, user:root database:laravel then tested the connect, it was all green, saved it and connected. I basically followed this tutorial https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/9

Comment: Stop: Apart from the name of the DB and the tag in your question, no Laravel and no PHP was involved in your question! That's also fine, because if it doesn't work with simple commandline tools, it can't work in more complex setups. However, that also means that adding that to the question is not helpful. Anyhow, if you want to clarify anything, you can edit your question instead. That said, just dumping a bunch of code here isn't useful anyway.

Comment: @UIrich I edited the initial question. The code I shared was not a 'dump' I thought it might be helpful, as it does relate to the database.

Comment: Let's not argue about whether the code should be called "dump" or not, it wasn't meant in a condescending way. What I meant was that this code without an explanation is not useful. Also, that as an alternative you can still edit your question to add that code. However, adding PHP, Laravel and a webserver to the picture when you DB doesn't behave as you expected isn't helpful, because it complicates things.

Comment: @UIrich thank you for clarifying. I'm trying my best but I guess I'm too new to really understand what a good question looks like. When I have some time, I'll try to re-word things to hopefully encompass all the details and to make it as descriptive as possible.

Comment: @UIrich, I think the question is more clear now... hopefully this can help address my issue...